# The database X is currently being loaded, but after 5 seconds, this request has been aborted

Tags: ravendb

I am getting the error in the title when executing the code below:

```
var documentStore = new DocumentStore
{
    ConnectionStringName = RavenDbInstance
};

documentStore.Initialize();

using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    registered = session.Query<TivoBoxMigrationServiceModel>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountNumber == accountNumber && x.AreaCode == areaCode);
}
```

This does not happen all the time, maybe 2-3 times a day.

Comment: I found the solution.

Two config values need to be updated:

Raven/Tenants/MaxIdleTimeForTenantDatabase

and

Raven/MaxSecondsForTaskToWaitForDatabaseToLoad

Comment: Thank you for replying to your own answer - this solved my issue. I was going crazy!

Comment: What is the valid range of configuration values ? Is -1 permissible ? (never unload ?)